# Openshift + Ansible : Failed when Play Approve node certificates when bootstrapping

Tags: ansible, openshift, okd

I'm trying to install Openshift Origin 3.11 with Ansible in offline mode. I got an issue when execute  deploy_cluster.yml and the error is :

```
TASK [Approve node certificates when bootstrapping] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Wednesday 15 April 2020  11:18:45 +0700 (0:00:00.056)       0:03:48.565 *******
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (30 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (29 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (28 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (27 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (26 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (25 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (24 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (23 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (22 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (21 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (20 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (19 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (18 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (17 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (16 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (15 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (14 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (13 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (12 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (11 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (10 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (9 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (8 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (7 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (6 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (5 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (4 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (1 retries left).

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
devoriginapp01             : ok=264  changed=45   unreachable=0    failed=1
devoriginapp02             : ok=94   changed=12   unreachable=0    failed=0
devoriginapp03             : ok=93   changed=12   unreachable=0    failed=0
localhost                  : ok=11   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0


INSTALLER STATUS ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Initialization              : Complete (0:00:11)
Node Bootstrap Preparation  : Complete (0:01:17)
Health Check                : Complete (0:00:00)
etcd Install                : Complete (0:00:17)
Master Install              : Complete (0:01:41)
Master Additional Install   : Complete (0:00:19)
Node Join                   : In Progress (0:03:19)
        This phase can be restarted by running: playbooks/openshift-node/join.yml
Wednesday 15 April 2020  11:22:02 +0700 (0:03:16.421)       0:07:04.987 *******
===============================================================================
Approve node certificates when bootstrapping ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 196.42s
openshift_node : Check status of node image pre-pull ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 30.61s
openshift_control_plane : Check status of control plane image pre-pull ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 30.32s
openshift_manageiq : Configure role/user permissions ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 3.70s
openshift_control_plane : Wait for APIs to become available ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 3.69s
openshift_node : Add firewalld allow rules --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 3.18s
openshift_node : Install node, clients, and conntrack packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.92s
openshift_node : Update journald setup ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.84s
tuned : Ensure files are populated from templates -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.74s
tuned : Restart tuned service ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.72s
tuned : Restart tuned service ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.68s
openshift_control_plane : Add firewalld allow rules ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 1.65s
openshift_ca : Install the base package for admin tooling ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 1.54s
openshift_control_plane : Wait for all control plane pods to come up and become ready -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.53s
openshift_master_certificates : Check status of master certificates -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.38s
openshift_node : Pre-pull node image --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.36s
openshift_examples : Remove defunct quickstart templates from openshift namespace ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 1.35s
openshift_node : pre-pull pod image ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.34s
tuned : Ensure files are populated from templates -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.26s
openshift_node_group : Make temp directory for templates ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.18s


Failure summary:


  1. Hosts:    devoriginapp01
     Play:     Approve any pending CSR requests from inventory nodes
     Task:     Approve node certificates when bootstrapping
     Message:  Could not find csr for nodes: devoriginapp02, devoriginapp03
```

Description about my environment :

- Ansible version

  ```
  ansible 2.6.5
    config file = /openshift-ansible/ansible.cfg
    configured module search path = [u'/home/origin/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
    ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
    executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
    python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 14:33:56) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
  ```
- OS Version (Master - Client same version)

  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
- Docker version

  Client:
   Version:           18.09.1
   API version:       1.39
   Go version:        go1.10.6
   Git commit:        4c52b90
   Built:             Wed Jan  9 19:35:01 2019
   OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
   Experimental:      false

  Server: Docker Engine - Community
   Engine:
    Version:          18.09.1
    API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
    Go version:       go1.10.6
    Git commit:       4c52b90
    Built:            Wed Jan  9 19:06:30 2019
    OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
    Experimental:     false

Steps that I did :

1. ansible-playbook openshift-ansible/playbooks/prerequisites.yml (Success)
2. ansible-playbook openshift-ansible/playbooks/deploy_cluster.yml

Additional :

```
[root@devoriginapp01 openshift-ansible]# cat inventory.ini
[OSEv3:children]
masters
nodes
etcd

[OSEv3:vars]
#openshift_additional_repos=[{'id': 'centos-paas', 'name': 'centos-paas', 'baseurl' :'https://buildlogs.centos.org/centos/7/paas/x86_64/openshift-origin311', 'gpgcheck' :'0', 'enabled' :'1'}]
ansible_ssh_user=origin
ansible_become=yes
openshift_deployment_type=origin
ansible_sudo=true
enable_excluders=False
enable_docker_excluder=False
ansible_service_broker_install=False
openshift_disable_check=disk_availability,docker_storage,memory_availability,docker_image_availability,package_version,package_availability
#docker_install=true
os_firewall_use_firewalld=True

containerized=True
os_sdn_network_plugin_name='redhat/openshift-ovs-multitenant'

#openshift_node_kubelet_args={'pods-per-core': ['10']}
#use HTPasswd for authentication
openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider'}]
openshift_master_htpasswd_file='/etc/origin/master/htpasswd'

deployment_type=origin

#define default sub-domain for Master node
openshift_public_hostname=console.origin.dev.com
openshift_master_default_subdomain=apps.origin.dev.com

template_service_broker_selector={"region":"infra"}
openshift_metrics_image_version="v3.11"
openshift_logging_image_version="v3.11"
openshift_logging_elasticsearch_proxy_image_version="v1.0.0"
openshift_logging_es_nodeselector={"node-role.kubernetes.io/infra":"true"}
logging_elasticsearch_rollout_override=false
osm_use_cockpit=true

openshift_metrics_install_metrics=True
openshift_logging_install_logging=True

openshift_master_api_port=8443
openshift_master_console_port=8443

[masters]
devoriginapp01 openshift_schedulable=true ansible_connection=local ansible_become=yes

[etcd]
devoriginapp01 ansible_connection=local ansible_become=yes

[nodes]
devoriginapp01 openshift_schedulable=true openshift_node_group_name='node-config-master-infra'
devoriginapp02 openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute' openshift_schedulable=True ansible_become=yes ansible_user=origin ansible_ssh_pass=P@ssw0rd
devoriginapp03 openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute' openshift_schedulable=True ansible_become=yes ansible_user=origin ansible_ssh_pass=P@ssw0rd

In /etc/hosts all nodes
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
#::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
x.x.x.x     DEVORIGINAPP01 console.origin.dev.com apps.origin.dev.com
x.x.x.x     DEVORIGINAPP02
x.x.x.x     DEVORIGINAPP03
```

For complete logs : [log.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-2pLXIXraRALTaRyNbe-ZvhaFtN3p8aw)

Could not find csr for nodes: devoriginapp02, devoriginapp03 but the master did it well. Anyone can help me to solve this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Retry the failing playbook with `-vvv` to see if you can get more info on the failure. If yes, edit your question and add some more details.

Comment: Updated in additional @Zeitounator

Comment: don't replace `-i` with `-vvv`, add it, The command you typed is trying to read your inventory as a playbook...

Comment: can you please check if os_firewall_use_firewalld=True in the inventory. also openshift_master_bootstrap_auto_approve=True

Comment: also i need you to check /etc/hosts entries

Comment: @Zeitounator I attached the complete logs in txt file, thanks for your instructions

Comment: @Mr.J I'm pretty sure about the /etc/hosts of these 3 servers because I sensored the IP. These 3 server can ping each other with the hostname. BTW what do you mean about openshift_master_bootstrap_auto_approve=True ?